# Grails 2.5: "dbm-gorm-diff" keeps generating the same changes over and over

Tags: grails, liquibase

Firstly, we deleted the database and then ran our app with `dbCreate="update"` to create a nice working base.

Then we ran:

```
grails dbm-generate-changelog baseline.xml
```

To create the script to generate our schema. We removed `dbCreate=xxx` from the `DataSource.groovy` and added the following in our `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
```

We then started our app, which created the DB, this time from the liquibase and all was good we thought.

Then we changed nothing (no changes to the source code), and did:

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff should_be_empty.xml --add
```

To our surprise, this generated 9 additional changeSets, all for indexes.

e.g:

```
<changeSet author="me(generated)" id="1438097433176-1">
    <createIndex indexName="site_id_uniq_1438097432189" tableName="adobe_message_service_config" unique="true">
        <column name="site_id"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="me(generated)" id="1438097433176-4">
    <createIndex indexName="IX_note_player" tableName="note">
        <column name="player_id"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

Very strange, where did these changes come from?  So we stopped and started the app again, and looked in the databasechangelog table and saw all 9 new changes sets had been run.

So we did this a second time, really expecting no changeSets:

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff should_be_empty_this_time.xml --add
```

and now it generated 5 change sets, all indexes again, all duplicates of the 9 it found before. Looking at the database itself, there is already an index with exactly the same name, table and column.  So the database already has the change, and now the same duplicate change is in the changeSets twice, and we don't know why it was in the original baseline from `dbm-generate-changelog`

What is going on?

Comment: We see exactly the same thing with our app. It's just something that we've become used to working around... run dbm-gorm-diff, pick through the generated changelog with a fine tooth comb figuring out which parts you need to delete, rince, repeat.

Comment: Does DATABASECHANGELOG contain records of your original baseline.xml?

Comment: @john Giotta, yes DATABASECHANGELOG contains all the original baseline changes, and the duplicates we see cropping up.  We have no idea why doing dbm-gorm-diff creates random indexes which are not defined in the domain model (the are not FK, PK or UK), and were not in the original bm-generate-changelog

Comment: I've had this problem before, but it had to do with correct dialect while using SQL Server. For example, datetime versus datetime2. Another time was when my local database was SQL Server 2008, but test was 2012. bigint was being set as numeric. Never a primary key incident.

Comment: @John, very interesting. In our case, I am hitting the same physical database with both tools.  I am guessing that the normal "dbCreate="update"" stuff, and the dbm-update stuff, both use the same datasource, so both use the same SQL and dialict settings in this case?  For our production, we have galera, so this may be a bigger issue when we come to deploy to that.