# Grails database migration gorm diff yields no changes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, liquibase

### Background

I have a relatively new Grails project using 3.0.14. I am looking to integrate liquibase for database migrations via the [Database Migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) (2.0.0.RC4).

I have a large enough domain model so far that I have used the plugin to 'seed' an initial changelog. This is straight from the docs, and works as intended:

```
grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy
```

What I am now trying to test/get working is the `dbm-gorm-diff` command, which will take changes to the domain model and create a changelog that can be applied. This is where I am running into issues.

The [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource) suggest removing the `dbCreate` block from the datasource to ensure that Hibernate doesn't do the updating, and Liquibase can take over. Great, exactly what I want.

### The Issue

When I remove `dbCreate`, Grails/hibernate still seems to update the database before the Database Migration plugin has a chance to do the diff. When doing the diff, it is already too late to see changes, so the changelogs do not contain the right data.

### Config

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: verify
            driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/liquibase_test
            username: dbuser
            password: dbuser
            logSql: false
            formatSql: true
```

(I am aware that the dbCreate is set to verify. More on this later)

### Steps Taken

1. Create a new postgres database - `dbcreate -U dbuser liquibase_test`
2. Run the initial changelog on the new database - `grails dbm-update`
3. Verify that the database is now up to date, and check that `select * from databasechangelog` equals the number of changes in `changelog.groovy`
4. Add a new simple domain class:

   ```
   class TestDomain {
       int testInt
   }
   ```
5. Run the plugin to get the diff - `grails dbm-gorm-diff add-simple-domain.groovy`. The command fails with an exception:

   ```
    :DataModel:dbmGormDiff
    Command execution error: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    DataModel:dbmGormDiff FAILED
   ```
6. Now, remove the config `dbCreate: verify` from above, and run again
7. This completes successfully without exception, but there are issues:

   - the command created `add-simple-domain.groovy`, but it has no mention of the new domain class I just created. (It has index/sequences, but I think this is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681564/grails-2-5-dbm-gorm-diff-keeps-generating-the-same-changes-over-and-over))
   - the new domain class **has been added** to the database(!?) (checked in PgAdmin)
   - the table `databasechangelog` still has the original row count, and even when interrogated no reference to the new domain class

So, I'm at a loss to explain what is going on. I can deal with the extra create/drop indexes & sequences, but I can't seem to get the liquibase stuff working. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

### Edit

I did some more digging into the NullPointer, and it seems to come from the class `liquibase/ext/hibernate/snapshot/ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:45`, where the plugin is trying to construct a foreign key to the inherited table id field (using `tablePerHierarchy false` for this inheritance). I couldn't find anything that seemed related to this error after a decent search.

### Edit #2

I have found an issue on Github for the `tablePerHierarchy` NPE: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/68

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment. There seem to be a requirement to use one of the dbCreate values... but only setting it to empty makes the plugin work. Did you find anything else since then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = 'none'` in my `application.groovy`. Interestingly, when I tried to instead put this same config in my `application.yml` it had no effect.

I suspect there may be other forces at play here as I tried replicating the behaviour on a fresh Grails project without issue.

For the time being I have settled on using the hibernate property in the groovy file, though I am still curious as to why I couldn't get the config to work for me like a vanilla project.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `application.yml` (or `application.groovy`) configuration for your datasource:

```
dataSource:
    dbCreate: none
```

Setting to "none" is not the same thing as removing `dbCreate` entirely - you need to set it explicitly to overwrite any defaults that are being set elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

"none" seems not to work for me when using JNDI datasources and still causes the ddl to run. I set it to "ignore" to be able to use db-migrations with JNDI datasources in Grails 3.0.x